# Should I create separate Bootstrapper for each WPF window?

Tags: wpf, prism, bootstrapper

I am new in WPF and Prism. I'd like to know if I should create new bootstrapper for each new window? For Example I have "Window1" where I select element from ListBox and click button "ShowDetails" and in the new window "Window2" I should see the details of my selection. I have windows and modules for them, but I'd like to know how and where I can register the module "Module2" for "Window2"?

Example of my Bootstrapper.

```
class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        var mainWindow = new Window1();
        mainWindow.Show();
        return mainWindow;
    }

    protected override IModuleCatalog GetModuleCatalog()
    {
        var moduleCatalog = new ModuleCatalog();
        moduleCatalog.AddModule(typeof(Module1));

        return moduleCatalog;
    }
}

"App.xaml.cs"

public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    { 
        var bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
        bootstrapper.Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: A bootstrapper is a all-in-one one-man-show... there should theoretically only exist one in an application. Where you have `moduleCatalog.AddModule(typeof(Module1));` , there should also be a line for module2

Comment: But how wpf will know that Module2 was registered for Window2?
In Window1 I have "Region1" and in the Window2 - "Region2".
When I try to register Module2 in bootstrapper I have an error "The region manager does not contain the Region2 region."

Comment: Can I suggest you start using Caliburn.Micro, it's way easier then PRISM and a lot less registration stuff. - To further trying to help you and as far as my PRISM knowledge allows me, you should register your Region2 to I thought in the RegionManager

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165370/Creating-View-Switching-Applications-with-Prism-4 - this seems like pretty comprehensive

Answer (score 1):

The Bootstrapper is used usually in the startup class of a WPF Application. Usually this will be the file App.xaml.cs in the standard template, which is the code-behind class of the App.xaml file. You override the method OnStartup and instantiate your Bootstrapper and call its run method. You can delay the startup of the bootstrapper until the override of OnStartup instead of writing this in the constructor of the App.xaml.cs class. You will then use the RegionManager in Prism and define regions in your XAML. If you have multiple independent Windows this is a bit different from the way Prism is intended to be used. There is the concept of a MainWindow or Shell which you define in the CreateShell method of the Bootstrapper class which is available in the Prism source code. Instead, have a main window and define regions and perhaps consider creating a mechanism for displaying additional windows in dialogs. It is possible partition up the MainWindow into multiple regions and inject user controls via the RegionManager. This is done via the activate method of the RegionManager.

Start up by reading the Patterns And Practices Guide and perhaps consider watching the videos of Mike Taulty upon Prism. The first video is here:

[Prism & Silverlight: Part 1 - Taking Sketched Code Towards Unity](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/mtaulty/Prism--Silverlight-Part-1-Taking-Sketched-Code-Towards-Unity)

There are many videos in the video series (10 in total) that will help you get started with PRISM.

An example of how to define a region in XAML is shown next:

```
<ItemsControl Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion" />
```

A PRISM region can be activated, e.g. through a DelegateCommand or ICommand bound to a button is the following code:

```
var viewA = new ViewA(); 
var regionA = (new RegionManager()).Regions["RegionA"]; 
regionA.Activate(viewA);
```

You will have to define multiple modules that implement the IModule Interface and add these to your ModuleCatalog as you already have done with ModuleA.